# regex to match exact phrases

Tags: regex

I would like to use regex to match exact phrases within a string.

For example, I have this expression.

```
^http:\/\/www\.tester\.co\.uk\/search\?keywords=(mountain|mountain\+top)
```

I would like the regex to match:
`.../search?keywords=mountain`

and NOT match:
`.../search?keywords=mountain**+side**`

I can't figure out in the expression how to tell it that I only want to match "mountain" or "mountain+top" exactly, but not "mountain+side".

Thanks!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIRYr.jpg)

Comment: Keep in mind that when using `.` in your regex you're allowing "any character" as that's what `.` means. You'd hence also match `wwwXtesterYcoZuk`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it!  Looks like you know about anchors since you used the `^` in the beginning, but you'd need an end of line anchor too, which is `$`

Edit: looks like @[ʰᵈˑ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000179/%CA%B0%E1%B5%88%CB%91) has found the regex you need -- with anchors, and escaping all special characters:

```
^http:\/\/www\.tester\.co\.uk\/search\?keywords=(mountain|mountain\+top)$
```

Comment: that worked! thanks so much :) just needed some $, but who doesn't ;)

Comment: You should escape the `.` otherwise you're allowing *any* character.

Comment: This would also match `keywords=mountainnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnntop`. Escape your plus or it'll mean "n repeated 1 to infinity times".

Comment: @wolke, hah!  good one.  Notice people's comments though, your regex can be improved since `.` and `+` have special meanings in regular expressions.

Comment: You also need to escape the `//` after `http`

Comment: @wolke I've removed my regex because there are some improvements to be made, but now that you know about the end of the line anchor, I think you can figure out what you need to do!  I don't know what phrases you expect will look like, but just remember to escape special regex characters if you need the character to exactly match.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I like it, looks like it suits OPs needs.  I can post the regex to the answer.  ++

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact phrase, use ^ and $, for example:

```
^http:\/\/www.tester\.co\.uk/search\?keywords=(mountain|mountain+top)$
```

Comment: You should escape the `.` otherwise you're allowing *any* character.

Comment: You also need to escape the `//` after `http`